# ExpressJS Route Parameter with Slash

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Im using ExpressJS. I want pass url as parameter.

```
app.get('/s/:url', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.url);
});

/s/sg.com                   //sg.com
/s/www.sg.com               //www.sg.com
/s/http://sg.com            //http://sg.com
/s/http://sg.com/folder     //http://sg.com/folder
```

How to correct the route such that everything afterr `/s/` will be considered as paramenter including slashes.

Thanks

Comment: You should pass the url as a querystring and then get it inside req.query when using express.

Answer (score 6):

Uh, if you want to stick a URL inside of another URL, you need to URLencode it. If you want to stick one in their raw and suffer the consequences, just use `app.get('/s/*'...` and then manually parse out the url with `req.url.slice(3)`. But hear me know and believe me later, URL Encoding is the right way to do this via the `encodeURIComponent` that is built in to JavaScript and works in both the browser and node.js.