# Node JS routing parameter with slash break routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-routing

I have the following routing definitions:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            "mainView":   {templateUrl: './partials/home.html'}
            }
        })
    .state('page', {
        url: '/page/:pageResource',
        views: {
            "mainView":   {templateUrl: './partials/page.html'}
            }
        })
```

On the home.html I have this ui-serf line:

```
<a ui-sref="page({pageResource: '{{page.resource}}'})">
```

Now, when I'm sending page.resource as `pageRest/1` I'm redirected to:
http://localhost/page/pageRest/1
Which send me back to `home` because of the `otherwise`.

Also, trying encoding it to `pageRest%2F1` (as suggested here [ExpressJS Route Parameter with Slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417800/expressjs-route-parameter-with-slash)) didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I tried to paste the url in the browser unaware it will decode the URL encoding once by it self.

Sending the URL double encoded fixed it:
http://localhost/page/pageRest%252F1